# How do you determine what should be a microservice?

Tags: design-patterns, microservices, scalability

If I'm building a scalable application that follows the microservice architecture, how do you decide what components of the application should be a service on their own? For example a website like facebook, it can be split into very broad services, newsfeed, messenger, search, etc, or it can be split into smaller services for each of those. What is the correct way to split an application into services to ensure scalability and efficiency?

Comment: Tell us what books have you read for this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking down microservices doesn't have any hard or fast rule. It depends on several factors. In my experience, it mostly relies on these two key factors.

- dependencies point of view
- business point of view

Let's revisit our idea of breaking down microservices. We would like to deploy our services as independent modules in such a way, each one's availability is independent. So we are working to achieve the goal of, one service down means only that one is unavailable at that time. Others are available.

Now, let's take two factors, I have mentioned.

(1) ***Dependencies***(models, libraries, dbs etc)

Let's take a simple scenario, just to grasp the idea. Imagine there is an online retailer platform. There we have a set of independent(segregated) db tables to store data of stock related to apparels. And it is in a such way that, it is harder to break down further (ex: different segregation for women clothes, men clothes etc).

So here, when we are going to develop api services, we can take a decision to provide a separate microservice for apparels (since we have a set of independently segregated tables for that section), but not break down any further as sections of apparel (since can't segregate those tables any more). Note that here, since we have a separate db segregation for apparels, any db failure for that segregation will not affect any other service (and vice-versa). And just think what would happen if we broke down services further (separate microservices for women clothes/men clothes etc). Since we have one common db segregation for all, if that common dependency gone down, all the services will go down. So no meaning of trying hard to break further since no gain of availability.

(2) ***Business***

I will take the above example here as well. Let's take business operations like client payments. Since it is a critical part of the business, most of the time, we can deduce that we are going to make a separate microservice for payments. Few minutes of unavailability of client payments, can cost the business millions. So we would like to make it as a separate independent microservice and give it a special attention when it comes to deployment.

Finally,since you have mentioned about facebook, I guess they would have these kinds of microservices break down.

- Authentication/Authorization
- User Data Management
- Media Content Management
- Messaging
- Calls
- Payments
- Push Notification Service
- Big Data Platform etc.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but with every one of these scenarios, the answer is, it depends. Part of your role as the architect is to determine this based on your scenario, and there are no real rules, just opinions. Also, there will be nobody standing over it judging you. At the end of the day the app just needs to be useful, scalable, reliable, and easy to maintain. This is the equivalent to a builder asking if the bricks should be round, square, or rectangle. It depends. If you equate this to a house, we are not talking about how the kitchen is arranged, more like the pipes in the basement. At some point nobody will care.

Comment: The problem is in the definition of well